# Taylor polynomial of composition equal up to order 2

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Consider two functions g and f, both from  $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and both twice differentiable. I want to show that $T_g\circ T_f$ agree with $T_{g\circ f}$ up to second order at some point $x_0$. $T_{g\circ f}$ is straightforward and a pretty simple expression. But for $T_g\circ T_f$ one gets a term $g''(f(x_0))\cdot(awfulterm-x_0)^2$ and I cannot see how these two should be equal up to second order. Any tips?

Comment: For $T_f\circ T_g$ do you mean $T_f$ at $g(x_0)$ and $T_g$ at $x_0$?

Comment: $T_f$ is the second Taylor polynomial of $f$
at $x_0$and $T_g$ the second Taylor polynomial of $g$ at $f (x_0)$, and $T_{g\circ f}$ the second Taylor polynomial of $g \circ f$
at $x_0$.

Answer (score 2):

To see that two functions agree up to second order at $x_0$, compute the values of the two functions and their first two derivatives at this point. We have
\begin{align*}
  T^{(k)}_{g\circ f}(x_0) &= (g\circ f)^{(k)}(x_0) & k \in \{0,1,2\} \\
  (T_g \circ T_f)(x_0) &= T_g (f(x_0)) \\
      &= g(f(x_0))\\
      &= (g \circ f)(x_0)\\
  (T_g \circ T_f)'(x_0) &= T_g'(T_f(x_0))T_f'(x_0)\\
       &= T_g'(f(x_0))f'(x_0)\\
       &= g'(f(x_0))f'(x_0)\\
       &= (g \circ f)'(x_0)\\
  (T_g \circ T_f)''(x_0) &= T_g''(T_f(x_0))T_f'(x_0)^2 + T_g'(T_f(x_0))T_f''(x_0))\\
&= T_g''(f(x_0))f'(x_0)^2 + T_g'(f(x_0))f''(x_0))\\
&= g''(f(x_0))f'(x_0)^2 + g'(f(x_0))f''(x_0))\\
&= (g\circ f)''(x_0)
\end{align*}